# Disable spring boot auditing in a jhipster generated application

Tags: jhipster, spring-boot-actuator

I would like to disable/limit auditing (`CustomAuditEventRepository`) in an application generated using jhipster.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify CustomAuditEventRepository so that it does nothing in add(), this is generated code, it's yours so you can do whatever you want with it.

Comment: I was hopping I would be able to control this externally like logging.

Comment: This is not configurable, if you think it should be you can open an issue on our github project

Answer (score 0):

Options 1: Disable audit event of `spring actuator`. Adding config properties to `application.yml` file:

```
management:
  auditevents:
    enabled: false
```

Refer: [AuditAutoConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/audit/AuditAutoConfiguration.java)

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@ConditionalOnBean(AuditEventRepository.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "management.auditevents", name = "enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
public class AuditAutoConfiguration {
...
}
```

Options 2: Add custom `AuditListener` bean

```
@Bean
public MyAuditListener auditListener() {
    return new MyAuditListener();
}



public class MyAuditListener extends AbstractAuditListener {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MyAuditListener.class);


    public MyAuditListener() {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAuditEvent(AuditEvent event) {
        ...
    }

}
```